# Shortcut in Linux mint Cinnamon to open active program if it exists, otherwise open a new one

Tags: linux, bash, keyboard-shortcuts, linux-mint

When having the icons for Chrome and file navigator in the quick launch bar in Windows or Ubuntu, pressing <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> would open chrome, and <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> would open the file navigator. I installed Linux mint 18 "Sarah" with Cinnamon and would like the mentioned behavior. What happens when I press <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> is that a new instance of chrome will be opened, regardless of whether I already have an active chrome session running or not.

First, I tried to enable the "superbar" by following [this guide](http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/tips-and-tricks-linux-mint-after-installation-mint-17-cinnamon-edition.htm), but that didn't work.

Then I found a way to fix this with help from [a blog post](http://10pm.ca/single-instance-and-keyboard-shortcuts-in-ubuntulinux-mint/), where shortcuts are bound to bash scripts. The first script works perfect for chrome, and the script to open the file manager had to be slightly modified. It turned out like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z `wmctrl -l | grep -i "google"` ]; then
    google-chrome-stable
else
    wmctrl -a "google"
fi
```

To give the script permission to be run, I type in the terminal:

```
chmod +x /path/to/script/scriptname
```

By opening the home menu and going to Keyboard and then shortcuts, assigning a custom shortcut where <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> is bound to "/path/to/script" makes it work.

To get the same behavior for the default file manager "Nemo" the following script makes it work:

```
#!/bin/bash
CLASSNAME=nemo.Nemo

if [ $(wmctrl -xl | grep "$CLASSNAME" | wc -l) -eq 1 ]; then
    nemo ~
else
    FOLDERNAME=$(wmctrl -xl | grep "$CLASSNAME")
    FOLDERNAME=${FOLDERNAME##*b1}

    wmctrl -a $FOLDERNAME
fi
```

And this script can be assigned to <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>.

My problem is that this method doesn't quite manage to get the exact behavior that I'm looking for. Since this has nothing to do with the placement of icons in the quick-launch bar, it is not flexible when I want to introduce a new icon, or switch places in the quick-launch bar.

Has anyone found an easier and better way to do this?